# TypeError while loading an .xlsx file with pivot tables using python 3.6

Tags: python, excel

Basically I am new to python, So would like to get some help here.

I have an excel workbook with two sheets in it, 1. Data, 2. Pivot tables.

I am getting an error while using this function, "openpyxl.load_workbook('Report.xlsx')

This is the error I am getting.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "excel_copy_by_header.py", line 15, in <module>
    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Report_0728.xlsx')
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a2-py3.6.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 275, in load_workbook
    pivot = TableDefinition.from_tree(tree)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a2-py3.6.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 79, infrom_tree
    obj = desc.from_tree(el)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a2-py3.6.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 86, in from_tree
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a2-py3.6.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 86, in <listcomp>
    return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a2-py3.6.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 99, infrom_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extLst'
```

As per my initial research, I couldn't able to figure out whether python 3.6 supports workbooks with pivot tables or not.

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The last stable `OpenPyXL` is _**2.4.8 (2017-05-30)**_, how do you get _**openpyxl-2.5.0a2**_? And Yes it supports Pivot Tables.

Comment: Thanks stovfl for your response, 2.5-0a2 was released on 08/14/17. If openpyxl supports pivot tables then can you help me why am getting that error.

I am not able to get anything from google related to this error.

Comment: You are using a **unstable** Version, dowgrade to **2.4**. Read: [Issues](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/857/inability-to-parse-sheets-with-pivot)

Comment: Thanks stovfl, The error is resolved after downgrade. However the pivot tables are converted to text format after saving back the excel using openpyxl.

Comment: Sorry, there is different support of Pivot Table created from Excel and `openpyxl`. It's Work in progress, extended in Version **2.5.x** but not finished yet. Read [Issues](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/295)